# React Router Invariant failed when Route or Link is used in an external package

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component library package where I own some components that I want to render into an app owned by a different team. I would like to be able to use stuff like `<Route />` and `<Link />` in my components package but I get an error like `Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>` when I try to do so.

The app in which I am rendering my components into has react router already set up and working. It renders a `<BrowserRouter />` near the top level as per usual. When trying to use `Link` or `Route` from any file within the app itself, it works fine. It just seems that I can't import router stuff from outside it and use it.

---

#### To Summarize

This does not work:

```
/* MyExternalComponent.js (this is in my external package) */

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyExternalPackage = () => (
  <Link to="/about">About</Link> // This throws the "Invariant failed" error
);
```

```
/* SomePage.js (this is in the actual app) */

import React from 'react';
import { MyExternalComponent } from 'my-external-package';

const SomePage = () => (
  <MyExternalComponent />
);
```

---

However, this DOES work:

```
/* MyExternalComponent.js (this is in my external package) */

import React from 'react';

const MyExternalPackage = ({ children }) => (
  <h1>hi</h1>
);
```

```
/* SomePage.js (this is in the actual app) */

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MyExternalComponent } from 'my-external-package';

const SomePage = () => (
  <MyExternalComponent />
  <Link to="/about" /> // I can render the link from the same context where I am rendering my component...
);
```

---

This also works:

```
/* MyExternalComponent.js (this is in my external package) */

import React from 'react';

const MyExternalPackage = ({ children }) => (
  {children} // Renders a link that routes me to /about
);
```

```
/* SomePage.js (this is in the actual app) */

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MyExternalComponent } from 'my-external-package';

const SomePage = () => (
  <MyExternalComponent>
    <Link to="/about" />
  </MyExternalComponent>
);
```

---

It seems for whatever reason that this issue only happens when I import `Route` or `Link` from within my package. When I render them as children of my component, everything works fine. I'm not sure why this is happening as it is clear that routing works within the app itself and I am rendering my component in a place where `<Link />` works fine.

Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i tried it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-custom-link-forked-84hks?file=/MyLink.js) and it works fine, please edit this sandbox with your example

Comment: Yep, I tried to reproduce a minimal example by creating a simple `@saadq/components` package with a component that uses `Link` and then importing that into an app that uses react router, but that worked fine. Unfortunately it looks like the issue might be some router magic happening in the app where I am trying to render.

Comment: Posted an answer with some more context... seems to be an issue with how i'm using `npm link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

To resolve issues like this where React/React Router end up having multiple instances in the consumer/dependency package due to `npm link`, you can add something like this in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
    'react-router': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-router'),
    'react-router-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-router-dom')
  }
},
```

This will ensure that only the consumer's version of React/React Router is used in both places.

---

**Original text**:

It turns out that the issue was because of how I was doing local development by using `npm link` in my components package + `npm link my-external-package` from the App. I'm guessing there is some `node_modules` issue happening because of this link..